# Using loop index inside of awk

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I apologize if this has been asked before. I think very similar questions have been asked but not one exactly like this.

I have a file that contains some columns

lets say it looks like this

```
1 3 4 12
3 5 8 12.1
. . . .
```

So its got columns of values. I would like to select the 2nd column and add a value to all elements in that column so that it might look like

```
1 3.2 4 12
3 5.2 8 12.1
. x+0.2 . .
```

But, I want that iterator to change based on some values in array that I look through. I would also like the file name to reflect that change. So we might say the original file is called

file.txt

but as I look through the file, I want the name to reflect what was added so that it would look like

file_0.txt  This is simply adding 0 to the original, or no changes, but its nice to have it in the same format to gather some values later.
file_0.2.txt
file_0.4.txt
... where I'm added an increment of 0.2 each time.

I'll mention that for my specific application, I have to select a subset of rows to do this on, so that's why I have NR bounds set.

```
file=${1?No file given}

boundsToTest=($(seq 0 0.2 5))

for i in "${boundsToTest[@]}"
do
     newFile=$(echo $file | awk -v i="$i" "NR==7,NR==126 {$3=$3+i}")
     newFileName="$(basename $file .txt)"_$i.txt
     mv $newFile ${newFileName}
done
```

So far this works and changes the name accoringly, but it is not adding the values to the column. Any help on passing the awk variable to do math inside of the file would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here - `echo $file | awk` is passing the file *name* through awk... surely you want to pass the file's *contents*?

Comment: Yes that's true. i'm trying to pass the contents and do some math on the selected column. I also want the filename to be a part of the new file name

Comment: ... so you want something like `awk -v i="$i" 'NR==7 || NR==126 {$3=$3+i}' "$file" > "$newFileName"` I think? Note the use of single quotes around the awk expression to prevent the shell from expanding `$3`

Comment: okay, so im using the `>` symbol now. like `awk -v i="$i" 'NR==7,NR==126 {$3=$3+i}' "$file" > newFile
        newFileName="$(basename $file .gjf)"_$i.gjf
        mv $newFile ${newFileName}
` but the math operation still isn't happening.

Comment: Sorry I forgot you need a statement to actually print the result, like `NR==7 || NR==126 {$3=$3+i; print}`

Comment: This works now with the `print` addition. Thank you! I'll post the full answer here in a moment unless you'd like to.

Comment: Actually there's a slight quirk to this. I want to copy all of the content of the file but only do that operation on those lines and now I'm only copying those specified lines.

Comment: ... so move the `print` outside the conditional: `NR==7 || NR==126 {$3=$3+i} {print}`

Comment: Okay this worked. Do you mind explaining why this works in a separate post?

Comment: AWK uses `pattern { action }` in the first case, *print* is the action for the *pattern*, `NR==7 || NR==126`, and the latter *print* has no pattern, thus prints everything.